# List only one category Python xml

Tags: python, xml, dom, lxml, minidom

I am trying to write a python program that uses DOM to read xml file and print another xml structure that list from only one node with particular selected attribute "fun".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<website>
    <url category="fun">
        <title>Fun world</title>
        <author>Jack</author>
        <year>2010</year>
        <price>100.00</price>
    </url>

    <url category="entertainment">
        <title>Fun world</title>
        <author>Jack</author>
        <year>2010</year>
        <price>100.00</price>
    </url>
</website>
```

I couldn't select the list from the URL having category="fun".

I tried this code:

```python
for n in dom.getElementsByTagName('url'):
    s = n.attribute['category'] 
    if (s.value == "fun"):
        print n.toxml()
```

Can you guys help to me to debug my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nb: One of your tags opens "Website" and attempts to close "website" - so you'll want to fix that one...

You've mentioned `lxml`.

```
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.fromstring(xml)
fun = root.xpath('/Website/url[@category="fun"]')
for node in fun:
    print et.tostring(node)
```

Comment: Thank you Jon! But I am using minidom in python to extract the data from xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAttribute`:

```
for n in dom.getElementsByTagName('url'):
    if (n.getAttribute('category') == "fun"):
        print(n.toxml())
```